# update XML using php issues with getElementsByTagName and identifying the correct childnode

Tags: php, xml, domdocument, appendchild

how do I identify the correct XML node based off a $_POST variable from a user submitted form.  Below is my current XML with a note on were I want the new XML data to be placed and the PHP that takes the form data and prepares it to be inserted into the XML document.

XML:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
    <content_sets>


<!-- The new article node will be placed inside of one of the content_sets child nodes. Either doc_types, video_types, image_types. -->
    <doc_types>

        <article>
            <doc_name>Test Proposal</doc_name>
            <file_name>tes_prop.docx</file_name>
            <doc_description>Test Word document. Please remove when live.</doc_description>
            <doc_tags>word document,test,rfp template,template,rfp</doc_tags>
            <last_update>01/26/2013 23:07</last_update>
        </article>
    </doc_types>



    <video_types>
        <article>
            <doc_name>Test Video</doc_name>
            <file_name>test_video.avi</file_name>
            <doc_description>Test video. Please remove when live.</doc_description>
            <doc_tags>test video,video, avi,xvid,svid avi</doc_tags>
            <last_update>01/26/2013 23:07</last_update>
        </article>
    </video_types>



    <image_types>
        <article>
            <doc_name>Test Image</doc_name>
            <file_name>logo.png</file_name>
            <doc_description>Logo transparent background. Please remove when live.</doc_description>
            <doc_tags>png,logo,logo png,no background,graphic,hi res</doc_tags>
            <last_update>01/26/2013 23:07</last_update>
        </article>
    </image_types>


</content_sets>
```

PHP on submit:

```
$file_type = $_POST['file_type'];
//This is where the node name comes from

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->load( 'rfp_files.xml' );

$doc->formatOutput = true;

$r = $doc->getElementsByTagName("content_sets")->getElementsByTagName($file_type);
*****//The above code is where my issue is coming from. I am not identifying the child node of content_sets correctly. 
$b = $doc->createElement("article");

$titleName = $doc->createElement("doc_name");
$titleName->appendChild(
    $doc->createTextNode( $Document_Array["name"] )
);
$b->appendChild( $titleName );


$r->appendChild( $b );

$doc->save("rfp_files.xml");
```

**I did not show the form or the rest of `article's` child nodes. If needed I can post more of my code.**

Comment: You *might* find something called *XPath* useful in cases like these, see http://php.net/class.domxpath - It allows you to look for *specific* elements, either a group or single ones based on their position and other things like attributes and their values.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When using `getElementsByTagName()`, you need to use the `item()` method so you can retrieve a specific node in the node list - even if there is only one item in the node list, you still have to do this.

`getElementsByTagName()` will always return a DOM Node List, so you either have to loop through the list, or you have to retrieve a specific item via the item() method - does that make sense? There is an example here: http://php.net/manual/en/domnodelist.item.php

Comment: Thanks for the info I am testing it now.

Comment: Is it possible to reference "item" with a string or the name of the childNode?

Comment: No - the item method takes only one parameter that must be an integer... eg. item(0), or item(1)

Comment: Is there another way I can find the childNode by using a string that matches its name?

Comment: If by saying "name" you mean Tag Name, then getElementsByTagName() does that already - it retrieves xml tags by their tag-name. But as you can see, the name of this method is in plural: getElement(s)ByTagName. So no matter what, it will always return a DOMNodeList Object, and DOMNodeList objects have only one property & one method - The property is "length" which tells you how many nodes are in a List, and the method is item() which allows you to retrieve a specific node by its numeric index. Unfortunately there isn't a singular version like getElementByTagName().

Comment: continued... Once you have retrieved a node with an example like so: $node = doc->getElementsByTagName('tag')->item(2);, then that node becomes a DOMNode object that inherits all of these properties & methods listed here: http://php.net/manual/en/class.domnode.php

Comment: There is also XPath, which allows you to be more specific, but it gets complicated very quickly, and I wouldn't be able to help with that at all. Here is a link: http://php.net/manual/en/domxpath.query.php

Comment: thanks for you help with my issues. You have helped me thing of a better way of approaching my issues. +1 checked. I will update my code one I have it working.