# store multiple tag value of an XML file in an array through xpath

Tags: php, xml, xpath

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Fetch specific tag with an attribute value from XML](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14562590/fetch-specific-tag-with-an-attribute-value-from-xml)

I have a XML file like the following:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<response uri="/crm/private/xml/SalesOrders/getRecords">
    <result>
        <SalesOrders>
            <row no="1">
                <FL val="SALESORDERID">580005000000187001</FL>
                <FL val="SO Number"><![CDATA[580005000000187002]]></FL>
                <FL val="Subject"><![CDATA[Sales order test from sri 02]]></FL>
                <FL val="Due Date"><![CDATA[2013-03-10]]></FL>
                <FL val="Status"><![CDATA[Created]]></FL>
                <FL val="ACCOUNTID">580005000000088096</FL>
                <FL val="Account Name"><![CDATA[Best Western Pavilions]]></FL>
                <FL val="SMOWNERID">580005000000052003</FL>
                <FL val="Sales Order Owner"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
                <FL val="SMCREATORID">580005000000052003</FL>
                <FL val="Created By"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
                <FL val="MODIFIEDBY">580005000000052003</FL>
                <FL val="Modified By"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
                <FL val="Created Time"><![CDATA[2013-01-17 20:32:19]]></FL>
                <FL val="Modified Time"><![CDATA[2013-01-17 20:32:19]]></FL>
                <FL val="Sub Total"><![CDATA[250]]></FL>
                <FL val="Tax"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
                <FL val="Adjustment"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
                <FL val="Grand Total"><![CDATA[250]]></FL>
                <FL val="Product Details">
                    <product no="1">
                        <FL val="Product Id">580005000000171125</FL>
                        <FL val="Product Name"><![CDATA[The Grilling Maestro]]></FL>
                        <FL val="Unit Price">10.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Quantity">20.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Quantity in Stock">0.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Total">200.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Discount">0.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Total After Discount">200.0</FL>
                        <FL val="List Price">10.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Net Total">200.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Tax">0.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Product Description"><![CDATA[null]]></FL>
                    </product>
                    <product no="2">
                        <FL val="Product Id">580005000000171131</FL>
                        <FL val="Product Name"><![CDATA[Uptown Deli   Soup du Jour]]></FL>
                        <FL val="Unit Price">25.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Quantity">1.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Quantity in Stock">0.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Total">50.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Discount">1.23</FL>
                        <FL val="Total After Discount">23.77</FL>
                        <FL val="List Price">25.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Net Total">48.77</FL>
                        <FL val="Tax">0.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Product Description"><![CDATA[null]]></FL>
                    </product>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Terms and Conditions"><![CDATA[iBanquet T and C]]></FL>
                <FL val="Description"><![CDATA[Sales Order from iBanquet]]></FL>
                <FL val="Discount"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
            </row>
            <row no="2">
                <FL val="SALESORDERID">580005000000134001</FL>
                <FL val="SO Number"><![CDATA[580005000000134003]]></FL>
                <FL val="Subject"><![CDATA[Test]]></FL>
                <FL val="CONTACTID">580005000000120009</FL>
                <FL val="Contact Name"><![CDATA[Sydney Lai]]></FL>
                <FL val="Carrier"><![CDATA[FedEX]]></FL>
                <FL val="Excise Duty"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
                <FL val="Sales Commission"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
                <FL val="Status"><![CDATA[Created]]></FL>
                <FL val="ACCOUNTID">580005000000088100</FL>
                <FL val="Account Name"><![CDATA[Best Western Sportstown Anaheim]]></FL>
                <FL val="SMOWNERID">580005000000052003</FL>
                <FL val="Sales Order Owner"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
                <FL val="SMCREATORID">580005000000052003</FL>
                <FL val="Created By"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
                <FL val="MODIFIEDBY">580005000000052003</FL>
                <FL val="Modified By"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
                <FL val="Created Time"><![CDATA[2012-11-08 14:51:50]]></FL>
                <FL val="Modified Time"><![CDATA[2012-11-08 14:51:50]]></FL>
                <FL val="Sub Total"><![CDATA[45]]></FL>
                <FL val="Tax"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
                <FL val="Adjustment"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
                <FL val="Grand Total"><![CDATA[45]]></FL>
                <FL val="Product Details">
                    <product no="1">
                        <FL val="Product Id">580005000000059016</FL>
                        <FL val="Product Name"><![CDATA[Beef Stoganoff]]></FL>
                        <FL val="Unit Price">14.95</FL>
                        <FL val="Quantity">1.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Quantity in Stock">-25.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Total">45.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Discount">0.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Total After Discount">45.0</FL>
                        <FL val="List Price">45.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Net Total">45.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Tax">0.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Product Description"><![CDATA[null]]></FL>
                    </product>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Discount"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
            </row>
            <row no="3">
                <FL val="SALESORDERID">580005000000118001</FL>
                <FL val="SO Number"><![CDATA[580005000000118003]]></FL>
                <FL val="Subject"><![CDATA[SAirpriya's Birthday]]></FL>
                <FL val="POTENTIALID">580005000000069001</FL>
                <FL val="Potential Name"><![CDATA[Sandeep]]></FL>
                <FL val="Due Date"><![CDATA[2012-10-17]]></FL>
                <FL val="Carrier"><![CDATA[FedEX]]></FL>
                <FL val="Excise Duty"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
                <FL val="Sales Commission"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
                <FL val="Status"><![CDATA[Created]]></FL>
                <FL val="ACCOUNTID">580005000000088090</FL>
                <FL val="Account Name"><![CDATA[Best Western Anaheim Inn]]></FL>
                <FL val="SMOWNERID">580005000000052003</FL>
                <FL val="Sales Order Owner"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
                <FL val="SMCREATORID">580005000000052003</FL>
                <FL val="Created By"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
                <FL val="MODIFIEDBY">580005000000052003</FL>
                <FL val="Modified By"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
                <FL val="Created Time"><![CDATA[2012-10-16 14:45:18]]></FL>
                <FL val="Modified Time"><![CDATA[2012-10-16 14:45:18]]></FL>
                <FL val="Sub Total"><![CDATA[1080]]></FL>
                <FL val="Tax"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
                <FL val="Adjustment"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
                <FL val="Grand Total"><![CDATA[1080]]></FL>
                <FL val="Product Details">
                    <product no="1">
                        <FL val="Product Id">580005000000059016</FL>
                        <FL val="Product Name"><![CDATA[Beef Stoganoff]]></FL>
                        <FL val="Unit Price">14.95</FL>
                        <FL val="Quantity">24.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Quantity in Stock">-25.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Total">1080.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Discount">0.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Total After Discount">1080.0</FL>
                        <FL val="List Price">45.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Net Total">1080.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Tax">0.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Product Description"><![CDATA[null]]></FL>
                    </product>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Discount"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
            </row>
            <row no="4">
                <FL val="SALESORDERID">580005000000070009</FL>
                <FL val="SO Number"><![CDATA[580005000000070011]]></FL>
                <FL val="Subject"><![CDATA[iBanquet]]></FL>
                <FL val="QUOTEID">580005000000070003</FL>
                <FL val="Quote Name"><![CDATA[iBanquet]]></FL>
                <FL val="Carrier"><![CDATA[UPS]]></FL>
                <FL val="Excise Duty"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
                <FL val="Sales Commission"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
                <FL val="Status"><![CDATA[Created]]></FL>
                <FL val="ACCOUNTID">580005000000058001</FL>
                <FL val="Account Name"><![CDATA[Hotel Skysurf]]></FL>
                <FL val="SMOWNERID">580005000000052003</FL>
                <FL val="Sales Order Owner"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
                <FL val="SMCREATORID">580005000000052003</FL>
                <FL val="Created By"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
                <FL val="MODIFIEDBY">580005000000052003</FL>
                <FL val="Modified By"><![CDATA[Adithya Buddhavarapu]]></FL>
                <FL val="Created Time"><![CDATA[2012-06-19 19:17:12]]></FL>
                <FL val="Modified Time"><![CDATA[2012-06-29 19:55:00]]></FL>
                <FL val="Sub Total"><![CDATA[20538]]></FL>
                <FL val="Tax"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
                <FL val="Adjustment"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
                <FL val="Grand Total"><![CDATA[20538]]></FL>
                <FL val="Product Details">
                    <product no="1">
                        <FL val="Product Id">580005000000059032</FL>
                        <FL val="Product Name"><![CDATA[Carrot Cake]]></FL>
                        <FL val="Unit Price">10.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Quantity">441.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Quantity in Stock">-882.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Total">4410.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Discount">0.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Total After Discount">4410.0</FL>
                        <FL val="List Price">10.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Net Total">4410.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Tax">0.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Product Description"><![CDATA[null]]></FL>
                    </product>
                    <product no="2">
                        <FL val="Product Id">580005000000059022</FL>
                        <FL val="Product Name"><![CDATA[Chicken Parmigiano]]></FL>
                        <FL val="Unit Price">15.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Quantity">122.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Quantity in Stock">-122.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Total">1464.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Discount">0.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Total After Discount">1464.0</FL>
                        <FL val="List Price">12.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Net Total">1464.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Tax">0.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Product Description"><![CDATA[null]]></FL>
                    </product>
                    <product no="3">
                        <FL val="Product Id">580005000000059030</FL>
                        <FL val="Product Name"><![CDATA[Coconut Cake]]></FL>
                        <FL val="Unit Price">10.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Quantity">1222.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Quantity in Stock">-1222.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Total">14664.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Discount">0.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Total After Discount">14664.0</FL>
                        <FL val="List Price">12.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Net Total">14664.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Tax">0.0</FL>
                        <FL val="Product Description"><![CDATA[null]]></FL>
                    </product>
                </FL>
                <FL val="Discount"><![CDATA[0]]></FL>
            </row>
        </SalesOrders>
    </result>
</response>
```

I need to show the name of the sales order owner name and their associated product name which is stored under `<FL val="Product Name">` of product tag.

My code is like:

```
$file_sales_content = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/SalesOrders/getRecords?authtoken=XXX&scope=crmapi"  
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML( $file_sales_content );   
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );
$items = $xpath->evaluate( '//FL[@val="Sales Order Owner"]' );
$sales_order_array = array();
for ( $i = 0; $i < $items->length; $i++ ) {
 array_push($sales_order_array,$items->item( $i )->textContent);
}
```

where `$file_sales_content` returns the above xml.

But I think some shortcut method is there. If so please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'd suggest setting up your code like this:

```
$file_sales_content = "https://crm.zoho.com/crm/private/xml/SalesOrders/getRecords?authtoken=XXX&scope=crmapi"  
$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML( $file_sales_content );   
$xpath = new DOMXPath( $doc );
$items = $xpath->evaluate( '//FL[@val="Sales Order Owner"]' );
$sales_orders = array();
foreach ( $items as $item) {
    $sales_order = array();
    $sales_order['name'] = $item->textContent;

    $products = array();
    $childItems = $xpath->evaluate( '../FL/product/FL[@val = "Product Name"]', $item );
    foreach( $childItems as $productName) {
       $products[] = $productName->textContent;
    }       
    $sales_order['product'] = $products;
    $sales_orders[] = $sales_order;
}
```

Comment: I have done as per your suggestion. But I am not getting the expected result. If I print the array $childItems. It's showing DOMNodeList Object ( ) DOMNodeList Object ( ) DOMNodeList Object ( ) DOMNodeList Object ( ) .

Comment: Yes, you need to further query each `$childItem` to get the values you want.  You haven't given any information about which specific values you want or how you want to represent them in a data structure, so the above is the most I can give you with the information you've given us so far.

Comment: Sorry for the deficiency of the information. Actually it will be like
array("name"=>"xxx","product"=>array("product_name1","product_name2","product_name3"));
I update my question. I need only owner name and their associated product name.

Comment: Thank you for that clarification.  Could you try my updated answer?

Comment: Thanks for the update. Let me check please.

Comment: If I print the final $sales_orders, it's showing 
Array ( [0] => Array ( [name] => Adithya Buddhavarapu [product] => Array ( ) ) [1] => Array ( [name] => Adithya Buddhavarapu [product] => Array ( ) ) [2] => Array ( [name] => Adithya Buddhavarapu [product] => Array ( ) ) [3] => Array ( [name] => Adithya Buddhavarapu [product] => Array ( ) ) )

Comment: My mistake.  I had forgotten that `<product>` was a child of a `<FL>` node.  Hopefully fixed now.  Could you try again?